# Is there Such Thing As The Opposite of Unique Constraint

Tags: postgresql, constraint

I want to be constrain my database with what is essentially the opposite of a `UNIQUE` constraint. I want to only be able to add a new row if some combination of fields *has* been added before.

Note: I am working within postgres.

Take the following datasets for example. I want a "`NON UNIQUE`" constraint on the following:

```
1, a, 1

1, a, 1

1, b, 1
```

I should not have been able to add the row `(1, b, 1)` since it has not appeared before. There are also other fields I don't want to constrain so it's not like all the entries are identical.

This may be a separate question, but I would also like to add the constraint that all rows with the same value in one column (*i.e.* `a` in the above example) have the same value in another.

So I want this to be impossible

```
1, a, 1

1, a, 1

0, a, 1
```

But this is ok

```
1, a, 1

1, a, 1

0, b, 1
```

I have looked around pretty heavily and the opposite of this is possible
with unique constraints, but I can't find anything that works for this.
Check constraints will only look at the row in question, and won't take into account the entire table's entries like a unique constraint would.

Is this even possible? Or is this now out of the realms of Postgres functionality, and must be done in-application.

Comment: Why is one valid and the other is not?

Comment: Just put your allowed combinations in another table, and point a foreign key at it

Comment: Just add a foreign key to the same table.

Comment: @Colin'tHart: FKs in Postgres need to reference something `UNIQUE`, so that won't work

Comment: How would you get the table populated in the first question?  Is it OK if they are inserted in the same transaction, or are the existing combinations set in stone and no newcomers are allowed?

Comment: Allowed contributions are not known beforehand, this is a simplified view but the data is not necessarily simple nor predictable.

Comment: So, then how is it intended to work?  If you need to make a conscious decision to create a new possibility, you could implement that by inserting the row into the referenced table of a FK constraint--although that would not then enforce "must always be at least two", it would at least enforce that the application grasped the implications of its actions.  If not that, then how do you envision new combinations being entered, if each row needs to be inserted before the other one?  The same statement?  Different statements of the same transaction?

Answer (score 2):

Your second goal can be achieved with an EXCLUDE constraint.

```
create extension btree_gist ;
alter table t add constraint adsfj exclude using gist (col2 with =, col1 with <>);
```

Answer (score 1):

Subqueries are not allowed in a CHECK constraint, or in the WHEN clause of a trigger, but you can use them inside a trigger function, something like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION my_little_trigger_function()
RETURNS TRIGGER
AS $$
DECLARE
   row_count int;
BEGIN
   row_count := (SELECT COUNT(*)
                 FROM ...
                 WHERE ... = NEW.x ...);
   IF (row_count = 0) THEN
       RAISE EXCEPTION 'I''m sorry, Dave. I''m afraid I can''t do that.';
   END IF;
   RETURN NEW;
END
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER my_little_trigger
BEFORE INSERT ON my_little_table
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE my_little_trigger_function();
```

Comment: Even though you can do this, it is not advised. You can run unto all kinds of problems (with concurrency or during restore of a backup for example).